# aggregating existing data by ids from mongodb in spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I'm wondering if Mongo-spark is able to handle a scenario where Im going to be importing json data from a stream, but for each file I want to first if there is a corresponding entity already within Mongo and if there is I'd like to manually merge the 2 documents.

The way that the imported data looks like is as follows

```
{orderId: 1290edoiadq, from: <Some_address_string>, to: <Some_address_string>, status: "Shipped"}.
```

The MongoDB that I have has the same data but the `_id` field contains the `orderId`. What I'm looking for is to get all the orders, and then check if they need to updated or inserted in.

**EDIT** Let me clarify what merging means. If I have an order with the same id, but their status is different then I'd like to update the status of the existing order in the db to be what is in the JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to manually merge the 2 documents.

Depends on your definition of `merge`.

If it's a one way direction, from the incoming json data stream to update documents stored in MongoDB, you could utilise [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option).

Since [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/getting-started/) version 1.1.0, if a dataframe contains `_id` matching the data in MongoDB, `save()` will use upsert. Which will update if matching `_id` exist, otherwise insert.

For example, to change to `status=delivered`:

```
> df.schema
  org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(_id,StringType,true), StructField(from,StringType,true), StructField(status,StringType,true), StructField(to,StringType,true))

> df.first()
  org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [1290edoiadq,sender,delivered,receiver]

> MongoSpark.save(df.write.option("collection", "order").mode("append"))
```

You just have to rename the `orderId` field name to `_id` before calling `save()`.

See [SPARK-66](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-66) and [MongoSpark: save()](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/MongoSpark.scala#L153) for more information.

However if by `merge` you mean a two direction update (incoming stream and MongoDB), then you would have to consolidate the changes first in Spark. Resolving any conflict as you deemed appropriate in the code.

Comment: Then it's a one-way direction, and you could utilise `upsert`. Just rename the `orderId` to `_id` before saving.

Answer (score -1):

I have not used MongoDB but had a similar use case. 
My scenario:
There is an incoming stream of events read from a kafka topic. These events need to be mapped and grouped by a key, for each key there might be a corresponding entry in a data store(HBase in my case, MongoDB in yours). If there is an entry, merge the keyed events into the existing entity if not create a new entity and save it to HBase. There are other complications in my case such as looking up multiple tables etc. but the gist of the problem appears to be similar to yours.

My approach and the challenges I faced:
I used the Kafka Direct Streaming approach, this gives me a batch(for this discussion is interchangeable with RDD) of data for the configured duration of time. The Direct Streaming approach would read from all kafka partitions but you have to set a manual checkpoint in the streaming context to make your program recoverable.

Now this RDD represents all the messages read within a configured duration.You can additionally configure the maximum size of this batch. When you do any processing on this RDD, the RDD is partitioned into chunks and each chunk is processed by an executor. Spark typically spawns one executor per core per machine in a cluster. I would advise you to configure the maximum number for your spark job. You can amortize the access to your data source (HBase in my case) on a per partition basis. So if your have  10 executors running parallel, be mindful that you can open 10 I/O connections in parallel to your data. Since your read should reflect the latest write on the entity, this is probably the most crucial aspect of your design.Can your data source guarantee consistency?

In terms of code your program would look something like this

```
dataStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
 // for each incoming batch, do any shuffle operations like groupByKey   first
// This is because during shuffle data is exchanged between partitions
 rdd.groupByKey().mapPartitions(eventsInPartition -> {
  // this part of the code executes at each partition.
  Connection connection = createConnectionToDataSource()

  eventsInPartition.forEachRemaining(eventPair -> {

  Entity entity = connection.getStuffFromDB(eventPair._1)
  entity.addNewEvents(eventPair._2) // your merge step
  connection.writeStuffToDB(eventPair._1, entity)

   })
 })
})
```

You start with foreachRDD to act on each incoming batch of data. Do any maps or transformation that can apply on each individual events in parallel first. groupByKey will shuffle the data across partition and you will have all events with the same key in the same partition. mapPartitions accepts a function that executes in a single partition. Here you can form connections to your DB. In this example since we do group by key, you have a pairRDD which be an RDD of a Tuple of event key + Iterable sequence of events. You can use the connection to lookup, merge, do other magic , write out the entity to the DB. Try different configs for batch duration, max cores, maxRatePerPartitions to control the flow of data based on how your DB and your cluster is handling the loads.